# Ionic-Toggle with Labels on each side

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ion-toggle

I am trying to add labels on each side to the ion-toggle component nested in an ion item. The text will always sit lower and I cannot get the text to move up.

I have tried various margins and paddings on the labels.  I have tried using Ion-note components, but I cannot get this text labels to slide up at all. There is no special css ion ion item or ion toggle.

```
 [![<ion-col  size-md="3" >
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label position="stacked">Is Technician</ion-label>
                    <div>
                        <label>No</label>
                        <ion-toggle formControlName="isTech" ></ion-toggle>
                        <label >Yes</label>
                    </div>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>]
```

Expected text to be aligned with the toggle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it works ;D.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
       <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <span>Plant</span>
            <ion-toggle slot="end" color="primary"></ion-toggle>
           <span class="ml-10">Animal</span>
        </div>
 </ion-item>
```

And I set the div display as flex. The code as below.

```
.ml-10{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.d-flex{
    display: flex;
}

.align-items-center{
    align-items: center;
}
```

[Click here to see the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQUq1.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-col  size-md="3" >
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label position="stacked">Is Technician</ion-label>
                    <div>
                        <label style="margin-top: 10px; position: fixed;">No</label>
                        <ion-toggle formControlName="isTech" style="margin-left: 35px;" ></ion-toggle>
                        <label style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 15px;  position: fixed;">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
```

This seems to work for the web, but for mobile devices, text is aligned at the bottom, so the margin needs to be adjusted for mobile as well. I would use the platform check in ionic to determine the margins to use.

Comment: This work only if there is no scrolling since the position is fixed, but making the position absolute does solve the problem.

Comment: Now if someone has a better suggestion for one implementation to work with different size labels, I would appreciate it

Comment: Why not use flexbox for your div?